# Using Splittext from GSAP in Nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, gsap, nuxtjs3

I'm using nuxtjs 3 and the @hypernym/nuxt-gsap package. I want to use splittext but I get the following error. Can you help with this?

```
const { $gsap } = useNuxtApp();
onMounted(() => {
  var childSplit = this.SplitText(".text-animation", {type: "lines"});
  console.log(childSplit);
});
```

My Error :

**index.vue:144 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SplitText')**

Comment: There is no `this` in the vue3 setup since the Vue instance hasn't been initial

Comment: How can I use this correctly? I looked at this url https://github.com/hypernym-studio/nuxt-gsap/tree/main/docs/club-plugins but I couldn't find how to do it. I'm new to NuxtJS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no this in the vue3 setup since the Vue instance hasn't been initial

change your code to

```js
const { $SplitText } = useNuxtApp()
onMounted(() => {
    const childSplit = $SplitText(".text-animation", {type: "lines"});
    console.log(childSplit);
});
```

also, add below in `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
// nuxt.config.ts

{
  gsap: {
    composables: true,
    clubPlugins: {
      splitText: true
    }
  }
}
```

*example from [github](https://github.com/hypernym-studio/nuxt-gsap/blob/4d83ba53c1b1d33bda23df56151bbb8c9898971b/docs/club-plugins/README.md#L493)*